# Como eu crio um método showOptionDialog que o valor padrão seja "não"?

Tags: java, swing

Eu quero com que as mensagens de confirmação de meu sistema se comportem com o valor padrão "não". Eu consegui isso fazendo desta forma:

```
private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    Object[] options = {"Yes", "No"};
    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(rootPane, "Deseja Excluir o Usuário?",
    "Titulo", 0, 3, null, options, options[1]);
```

[image: screenshot]

Só que eu quero criar um método para reutilizar esse trecho de código e não estou conseguindo. Eu tenho que sobrescrever o método `showOptionDialog` do java?

Eu quero passar como parâmetro a mensagem a ser exibida e quero que me retorne a opção selecionada pelo usuário.

Como faria isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso:

```
    private static boolean perguntar(
            Component c,
            String mensagem,
            String titulo,
            boolean defaultOpt)
    {
        Object[] options = {"Sim", "Não"};
        int resposta = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                c,
                mensagem,
                titulo,
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                null,
                options,
                options[defaultOpt ? 0 : 1]);
        return resposta == 0;
    }
```

Para chamar esse método:

```
boolean aceitou = perguntar(rootPane, "Deseja excluir o usuário?", "Título", false);
```

Ele vai retornar `true` se o usuário clicar no botão "Sim" e vai retornar `false` se ele clicar no "Não", fechar a janela, apertar <kbd>Esc</kbd> ou apertar <kbd>Enter</kbd> imediatamente após a janela abrir.